Existence of $\lfloor\text{deg}(v)/2\rfloor$ disjoint cycles sharing a single vertex
Prove that every simple graph $G$ contains a vertex $v$ and a set of $\lfloor\text{deg}(v)/2\rfloor$ cycles such that no two cycles in the set share an edge and the only common vertex among these cycles is $v$.
The problem comes from a graph theory problem set shared by a Brazilian friend. It is the only problem I haven't been able to solve, and I'd appreciate guidance or hints.
Here is my approach so far:
I attempted to prove this by induction on $\delta(G)$, the minimum degree of the graph.
If $\delta(G) \leq 1$, we can take the node with minimum degree and no cycles, trivially satisfying the condition. Assume the statement holds for all graphs with $\delta(G) = k \geq 1$. Let $G$ be a graph with $\delta(G)=k+1$. Take a vertex $u$ such that $\text{deg}(u)=k+1$. Consider the subgraph $G'$ obtained by removing one neighbor of u, say $w$. In $G'$ we have $\delta(G')=k$, so by the inductive hypothesis, there exists a vertex $v$ in $V(G')$ that satisfies the required conditions. Now analyze $v$ in $G$. If $w$ is not neighbor of $v$, or if it is a neighbor but $\text{deg}_{G'}(v)$ is even, then $v$ works $G$ as well. However, I am struggling to extend this to the case where $w$ is neighbor of $v$ and $\text{deg}_{G'}(v)$ is odd.
At this point, I am unsure how to proceed. I would appreciate feedback on my inductive hypothesis approach or suggestions for other methods to prove this result. Thank you!

Hint: choose a maximal path in $G$.

Thanks! With that observation I was able to construct the set using the edges of any endpoint and complete the proof.

Your approach seems hard to analyze, as the induction doesn't really give you much to work with. Here's an approach as hinted to by koifish.
Let $P$ be a longest path in $G$, and let $v$ be one of the ends of $P$. By the maximality of $P$, $N(v)\subset V(P)$. Let $d$ denote the degree of $v$, and enumerate the neighbours $v_1, \dots, v_d$ of $v$ along $P$ starting at $v$. For $j\in \{1,\dots, d-1\}$ let $P_j$ denote the $v_jv_{j+1}$ subpath of $P$. Now, $P_j$ is disjoint from all such paths except potentially $P_{j-1}$ and $P_{j+1}$, and $C_j$ formed by joining the ends of $P_j$ to $v$ forms a cycle. Let $\mathcal{C} =\{C_j:j\text{ is odd}\}$. Then $|\mathcal{C}|=\lfloor\frac{d}{2}\rfloor$, and all $C_j$ are pairwise edge-disjoint, sharing only the vertex $v$. This completes the proof.
